# SQL: exact row match given certain elements

Tags: mysql, sql

this is my first time posting here. I don't seem to find the answer to my problem.

So... I'm arranging a DB for a school project, a cookbook that **only** shows recipes that can be made with existing elements from the "shelf".
These ingredients have to have an exact ingredients match.

user:

```
+---------------+------+----------+----------+
|     email     | name | lastname | password |
+---------------+------+----------+----------+
| pal@mail.com  | John | Potato   | password |
| they@mail.com | Mary | Carrot   | password |
+---------------+------+----------+----------+
```

shelf:

```
+---------+------------+---------------+
| shelfID | ingredient |     user      |
+---------+------------+---------------+
|       1 |          1 | pal@mail.com  |
|       2 |          2 | pal@mail.com  |
|       3 |          3 | pal@mail.com  |
|       4 |          4 | pal@mail.com  |
|       5 |         10 | they@mail.com |
|       6 |         12 | they@mail.com |
+---------+------------+---------------+
```

This is my recipe_ingredient *relationship* table

recipe_ingredient:

```
+--------+------------+
| recipe | ingredient |
+--------+------------+
|      1 |          1 |
|      1 |          2 |
|      1 |          4 |
|      1 |         10 |
|      2 |          1 |
|      2 |          2 |
|      2 |          3 |
|      2 |          4 |
|      3 |          2 |
|      3 |          3 |
|      3 |         15 |
+--------+------------+
```

I've tried this query:

```
    SELECT 
    rec_ing.recipe, shf.ingredient, shf.user
FROM
    recipes_ingredients AS rec_ing
        INNER JOIN
    shelf AS shf ON rec_ing.ingredient = shf.ingredient
        INNER JOIN
    users AS usr ON shf.user = usr.email
WHERE
    usr.email = 'pal@mail.com'
```

that returns this table:

```
+--------+------------+--------------+
| recipe | ingredient |     user     |
+--------+------------+--------------+
|      1 |          1 | pal@mail.com |
|      1 |          2 | pal@mail.com |
|      1 |          4 | pal@mail.com |
|      2 |          1 | pal@mail.com |
|      2 |          2 | pal@mail.com |
|      2 |          3 | pal@mail.com |
|      2 |          4 | pal@mail.com |
|      3 |          2 | pal@mail.com |
|      3 |          3 | pal@mail.com |
+--------+------------+--------------+
```

Although it's true that the *Recipe 1* contains ingredients from my shelf, it's also missing *Ingredient 10*

```
+--------+------------+
| recipe | ingredient |
+--------+------------+
|      1 |          1 |
|      1 |          2 |
|      1 |          4 |
|      1 |         10 |
|    ... |        ... |
+--------+------------+
```

I'm trying to only get this kind of result set.

```
+--------+------------+
| recipe | ingredient |
+--------+------------+
|      2 |          1 |
|      2 |          2 |
|      2 |          3 |
|      2 |          4 |
+--------+------------+
```

Because Recipe 2 contains all elements from my *shelf*

I have been going around all day with this problem ... What could be missing?

Comment: Please try posting the `usr` and `shf` table as well for more clarity.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit tricky, because you need to aggregate your current query by recipe, but you also need the original query to get back the full records.  Sadly, MySQL does not support common table exprrssions or other features which could give us a less verbose query.

```
SELECT 
    rec_ing.recipe,
    shf.ingredient,
    shf.user
FROM recipes_ingredients AS rec_ing
INNER JOIN shelf AS shf
    ON rec_ing.ingredient = shf.ingredient
INNER JOIN users AS usr
    ON shf.user = usr.email
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT rec_ing.recipe
    FROM recipes_ingredients AS rec_ing
    INNER JOIN shelf AS shf
        ON rec_ing.ingredient = shf.ingredient
    LEFT JOIN users AS usr
        ON shf.user = usr.email
    WHERE
        usr.email = 'pal@mail.com'
    GROUP BY rec_ing.recipe
    HAVING COUNT(usr.email) = COUNT(*)
) t
    ON rec_ing.recipe = t.recipe
WHERE
    usr.email = 'pal@mail.com'
```

The basic strategy here is to just do one additional join to a subquery which identifies all recipes where every ingredient belongs to a given user.  The critical part is the following:

```
HAVING COUNT(usr.email) = COUNT(*)
```

This checks that the total number of rows for a given recipe matches the number of rows which have been assigned to a given user.

Comment: I knew this project would not be as simple as it looked! **Thanks!** Let me analyze and understand more carefully this answer.

Comment: Wouldn't this method need to be applied to the recipes instead of the users?

Comment: @Kerberos `COUNT(usr.email)` counts the number of non `NULL` (i.e. matching) ingredients for a given user.